# Linq to Entities how to update record in one database access

Tags: linq, entity

I want to update many records in a 10 million record database. Examples here suggest that updates can be done like this:

```
Customer c = (from x in dataBase.Customers
             where x.Name == "Test"
             selext x).First();
c.Name = "New Name";
dataBase.SaveChanges();
```

but this looks like two trips to the database.  One to get the record and the other to save the record.  If I updated a thousand records in one call, I think this would have to pull 1,000 records from the database to my WCF server, make the change, then push the 1,000 records back over the LAN to the database server.

In the old days, "Update Customers set Name = 'Test' where Year < 1960 " would be one instruction over the LAN and the work is done at the database server.

Is there something like this in Linq to Entities?

*BTW:  This is a simple example of what I'm trying to achieve, I actually have hundreds of commands to issue and I don't want 2*hundreds of trips to the database, nor do I see the need to bring all the data from the database to WCF just to change it and send it back!*

Answer (score 3):

As you suspected. If you have 1000 records, you would indeed see 1001 database requests for this operation. ORM's are great for pushing objects into memory, working with them and then updating them. They are not good for bulk operations. In this case your best bet would be to either use ADO.Net and pass your update statement via code, or to put your bulk update command in a stored proc and map that proc to a function in EF.